# Managing MongoDB Embedded documents With Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I am working with Java and MongoDB driver 3.10.1, on a collection where I need to store payments with dates so it looks like this

```
"paid" : {
                "price" : "100",
                "Date" : "2019-10-06T00:00:00Z"
        },
```

However, I successfully inserted that one and update it using this query:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
Document payment =  new Document("price" , paid_price)
                .append("Date", date);
collection.updateOne(eq("_id", new ObjectId(guest1)),
         combine(set("paid",payment ),currentDate("lastModified") ));
```

So, My Question is: How do I add multiple of these embedded documents inside paid so it would look like the example below and how do I access each of them using an easy way ??

```
{
    "paid": [{
            "price": "100",
            "Date": "2019-10-06T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "price": "100",
            "Date": "2019-10-06T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "price": "100",
            "Date": "2019-10-06T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

the last question is: what would be the best practice using mongodb with object oriented programming? json parser for each class as an example ?? or creating methods that access mongo and return data ?

Comment: Look into the `$push` operator.   You want to push a new subdoc onto that `paid` array, not `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps. This is how I would do it.

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
 //import org.bson.Document;
```

To embed objects you needs to declare the objects you plan to use. Instead of looping through an initializing an object and adding it.  I created the three objects I plan to add to the array.

```
 Document root= new Document();
 ArrayList rootPaid= new ArrayList();
 Document rootPaid0 = new Document();
 Document rootPaid1 = new Document();
 Document rootPaid2 = new Document();
```

On those sub objects I then populate the information.  You could iterate through this process and add as many objects as you desired.  Each iteration you would have to initialize the document object, populate information, and then add to the root.

```
 rootPaid0.append("price","100");

 rootPaid0.append("Date","2019-10-06T00:00:00Z");

 rootPaid1.append("price","100");

 rootPaid1.append("Date","2019-10-06T00:00:00Z");

 rootPaid2.append("price","100");

 rootPaid2.append("Date","2019-10-06T00:00:00Z");
```

At this point I merge all the objects together to make the desired json.

```
 if (!rootPaid.isEmpty()){
 root.append("paid",rootPaid);
 }
 if (!rootPaid0.isEmpty()){
 rootPaid.add(rootPaid0);
 }
 if (!rootPaid.isEmpty()){
 root.append("paid",rootPaid);
 }
 if (!rootPaid1.isEmpty()){
 rootPaid.add(rootPaid1);
 }
 if (!rootPaid.isEmpty()){
 root.append("paid",rootPaid);
 }
 if (!rootPaid2.isEmpty()){
 rootPaid.add(rootPaid2);
 }
 if (!rootPaid.isEmpty()){
 root.append("paid",rootPaid);
 }
```

UALA! you have your JSON.

```
 System.out.println(root.toJson());
```